# jQuery value slider with image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

Does anybody knows a good solution (or maybe a plugin) to create a slider like on the picture below(with jquery, jquery ui, any other lib)?

[image value slider img](http://pictat.com/show.php?i=/2013/4/5/43539slider.png)

So the idea is that basically you slide the background image, not one little indicator.

### UPDATE

I'm trying to connect the ui slider with draggable property, but with not much luck. You can play here: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/usuxog/1/edit)

Comment: should it be an infinit slider. is it required that you can define different ranges ?

Comment: it shouldn't be infinite, there is a min and max value. the image is wide and contains all the values, so I can use it. I know it would be more elegant to repeat only a section of it, but I need a relatively quick solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
You can make that image. place it inside a div make it overflow hidden. Make it draggable.

When the image is dragged, call the slider function of slider. This way it will look like a slider.

Comment: Good idea. I've tried without the slider function, just calculating the offset of dragging, but it's not good when it is dragged a little bit aggresive. So I need the slider function, too, but I don't know how to trigger it.

http://jsbin.com/usuxog/1/edit

Comment: Your above link works ?? .. Can you explain what' snot working as i can see the scale image gets dragged as jus needed :).

Comment: basically I was on the wrong idea. I thought that I need to trigger somehow a slider when the div is dragged, to get the most accurate values, but it can be calculated from the dragged divs position, too. So becuase the solution is based on your idea, I accept your answer :) Thanks!